# How to check whether a repository exist or not?

Tags: mercurial, firefox-addon

I want to check whether repository exist on the given path or not before executing the process below..any ideas ?

```
var exe = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/filelocal;1'].
                     createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);

exe.initWithPath("HG.EXE");

var process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].
              createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);

Process.init(exe);

args = ["init", "D:\\testRepo\\"];
process.run(blocking, args, args.length);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could use

```
hg --cwd the/path/you/want/to/test root
```

That command tells you if there is a repository at `the/path/you/want/to/test` or above. Look at the exit code of the command to see if it succeeded.

You will also need to compare the root printed by the command with your actual directory -- it could be that there is a repository at some higher level and then `hg root` will report that.

Comment: Nitesh: I'm glad you could use it, feel free to accept this answer as the correct answer :-)

Comment: This answer may be out of date.  On hg 2.6.1 on Windows, I get an `abort: repository ... not found!` on c:\dev\tools but normal output on c:\dev.

Comment: @Kev Thanks for the comment! The `-R` flag only works if the path you test is the root of a repository, use `--cwd` instead if you also want it to work with paths inside repositories. I've updated the answer to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply check if the `.hg` subdirectory exists (this only works if you are checking the root of the repository, not from within a folder that would be part of your repository).